# res.render('/index') is not working in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to render profile page from my routes.js file

```
app.get('/loadProfile', function (req, res) {
    res.render('profile', {
        user: req.user,
        FBDates: FBDataset["Dates"],
        FBImpressions: FBDataset["Impressions"]
    });
});
```

After running server the control comes to this /loadProfile,but not rendering the profile page ,in terminal I'm getting the following

```
GET /loadprofile 200 291ms - 3.97kb
```

If I check in browser that page loaded in network under inspect element[image] how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The url in the image is "localhost:8080/profile". To see the profile view rendered, navigate to "localhost:8080/loadprofile".

Comment: Yes you are correct if I directly give like what you told the page will be rendered but in my case the loadProfile page automatically to be loaded once I click the submit button